# Difference between article tag , paragraph tag, section tag in html?

Tags: html

What is the difference between these tags `<p> <article> <section>` in html?

Answer (score 1):

According to w3schools:

[Section tag:](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_section.asp)

> The section tag defines sections in a document, such as chapters, headers, footers, or any other sections of the document.

[p tag:](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp)

> The p tag defines a paragraph.

[article tag:](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_article.asp)

> The article tag specifies independent, self-contained content.